# Multiple alignment for multiline equation within itemize environment

Tags: equations, align, itemize, split

I'd like to have a multiline equation. Within this equation there should be 2 alignments.
So the last (in front of 'fff') '+' sign should be aligned to the 'eee'.
And 'aaa' from the first item should be below 'abc' from the second item.

This is what my code looks like:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item blabla1
        \begin{equation}
            abc = def
        \end{equation}
    \item blabla2
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            aaa &= bbb \\
            &= ccc + ddd \\
            &= eee \\
            &+ fff
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Both + signs? Please make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink to the way you're presenting the material. Anyway, here's a working solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item blabla1
\begin{align}
  abc &= def \\
\shortintertext{\item blabla2}
  \begin{split}
  aaa &= bbb \\
      &= ccc + ddd \\
      &= eee \\
      &+ fff
  \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]